# MVC5 aspnet identity how to disable claims

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

Is there any way to disable claims (and may be roles too) from aspnet identity?
I don't want extra tables in my db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found one good example from asp.net blog.](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2013/12/12/a-simple-implementation-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity.aspx)